# How to insert Select Query Result into a PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I m using SQL SERVER 2012.

Query:1

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Insurance, ChargeValue, CreatedDate
    FROM dailychargesummary
    WHERE MonthName='June 2017'
) m
PIVOT (
    SUM(ChargeValue)
    FOR CreatedDate IN ([06/22/2017], [06/23/2017],[06/30/2017])
) n
```

Output of above query is looks like below:

[image]

Now I m hard coding all the dates of a month inside the Pivot Query such as 06/01/2017, 06/02/2017, etc., After searching in the Google, I got the following query to display all the dates of a given month number.

Query 2:

```
DECLARE @month AS INT = 5
DECLARE @Year AS INT = 2016

;WITH N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)FROM N,N a)
SELECT datefromparts(@year,@month,N) date FROM tally
WHERE N <= day(EOMONTH(datefromparts(@year,@month,1)))
```

Output looks like below:

[image]

Can anyone please guide me how to use the Query2 inside the pivot in Query1 to automate the dates.

Comment: Do you really want a column for every day... or just the days that are in your data?

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server dynamic pivot".

Comment: @scsimon for each and every day of the given month, becoz I want to know which days data are missing

Comment: Ok, then you do not want a dynamic pivot (though it is powerful). Standby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dynamic query, to get the pivot list dynamically

first assign the dates list to a variable.

```
Declare @pivot_list varchar(8000)= ''
DECLARE @month AS INT = 5
DECLARE @Year AS INT = 2016

;WITH N(N)     AS (SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
      tally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)FROM N,N a)
select @pivot_list = stuff((SELECT ','+quotename(convert(varchar(15),datefromparts(@year,@month,N),101)) 
                            FROM tally
                            WHERE N <= day(EOMONTH(datefromparts(@year,@month,1))) for xml path('')),1,1,'')


--Print @pivot_list
```

Now use the `@pivot_list` variable in the pivot list

```
Declare @sql varchar(8000)
set @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Insurance, ChargeValue, CreatedDate
    FROM dailychargesummary
    WHERE MonthName='June 2017'
) m
PIVOT (
    SUM(ChargeValue)
    FOR CreatedDate IN ('+@pivot_list+')
) n'

--Print @sql

Exec @sql
```